# Hide database from a role in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried `REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE ABC FROM ROLE XYZ` under `ACCOUNTADMIN` and got a success message.

When I switch to role `XYZ` I still see the `ABC` database but it appears empty. The database is also still in the list when running `show databases` under this role.

How do I make it so that this role cannot see the database at all?

By the way, this issue prevents our Mode connection to Snowflake from listing the available tables in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Create two databases : db1 and db2, for example, using the ACCOUNTADMIN role:

create database db1;
create database db2;

Then create two roles,one for database db1 and another for database db2

create role db1;
create role db2;

Now, grant usage on database db1 to role db1, similarly with role db2.

grant usage on database db1 to role db1;
grant usage on database db2 to role db2;

When you switch to role db2, you wont see db1 database and vice versa.
Also, when you run :

show databases;

say, while you set your role to db1,
you will not see database db2 in the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also had usage monitoring and thus had to do `revoke MONITOR USAGE on account from role XYZ`. I suspect this is a very corner case not affecting many people. :(